# Does $E[X_n^k]<\infty$ for $k>0$ imply $E[X_n^k]=b$ for some real $b$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

If you see that $E[X_{n}^k] < \infty$ for $k > 0$ (where $X_n^k$ is a random variable), is it safe to assume that $E[X_{n}^k]=b$ for some $b \in R$ (reals)?

Comment: My first reaction was to say, yes, of course.  The expectation, if it exists,  is a real number and saying "[tex]< \infty[tex]" is just saying that it does exist so is a real number.  My second that was that you had a situation with complex numbers.  But the complex numbers are not an ordered field so your "[tex]< \infty[/tex]" would not makes sense.  The last possibility, as silly as it seems, is that you are asking "is saying 'x is a real number' the same as saying 'there exist b in R such that x= b'?  Yes, of course!

Comment: for odd $k$, there's the possibility that $X_n \equiv -\infty$ allows for $E[X^k_n] < \infty$.

Comment: That's what it means, so yes.